# Restkit 0.20.x routeclass changes

Tags: ios, restkit

Okay so prior to upgrading to 0.20.x i was routing my class like so

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[Player class] toResourcePath:@"/player" forMethod:RKRequestMethodGET];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[Player class] toResourcePath:@"/player" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[Player class] toResourcePath:@"/player" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPUT];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[Player class] toResourcePath:@"/players" forMethod:RKRequestMethodDELETE];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[WTFGameInfo class] toResourcePath:@"/game"forMethod:RKRequestMethodGET];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[WTFGameInfo class] toResourcePath:@"/game" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[WTFGameInfo class] toResourcePath:@"/game/:gameID" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPUT];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[WTFGameInfo class] toResourcePath:@"/games" forMethod:RKRequestMethodDELETE];
```

however It has changed ever so slightly to using PathPatterns and i am wondering whether i cal leave the string in the resource path exactly the same or i have to change it to look something like.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Player class] pathPattern:@"/player/:_id" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];//posibly do it for _fbID;
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Player class] pathPattern:@"/player/:_id" method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];//posibly do it for _fbID;
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Player class] pathPattern:@"/player/:_id" method:RKRequestMethodPUT]];//posibly do it for _fbID;

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[WTFGameInfo class] pathPattern:@"/game/:_id" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];//posibly do it for @"/game/:gameID";
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[WTFGameInfo class] pathPattern:@"/game/:_id" method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];//posibly do it for @"/game/:gameID";
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[WTFGameInfo class] pathPattern:@"/game/:_id" method:RKRequestMethodPUT]];//posibly do it for @"/game/:gameID";
```

can anyone clarify this for me? thanks...

Comment: Note the leading `/` in your route paths: when I updated to 0.20.x, I noticed that my requests were getting routed to the wrong URL: for example, if your base URL is `http://server/api` then with your routing your request URL would look like `http://server/api/player` in 0.10.x, but in 0.20.x it could be `http://server/player`. A route path with a leading slash now seems to be treated as an absolute path. Removing the leading slash fixed this for me, so that the route is treated as relative to the base URL.

Comment: I discovered this quite quickly as well, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine :

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Player class] pathPattern:@"player/:playerId" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];
```

And to get your player, something like that:

```
Player *player = [Player new];
player.playerID = 2;
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObject:player path:nil parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
    // Request 
} failure:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Now although i do get a response body which looks like    `response.body={
  "player": [
    {
      "_id": "50585c86ded998e77a000002"
    }
  ]
}`
But it fails with code 1001,"unable to find any mapping for the given content"

Comment: Okay apparently you should return an array if there is less than 2 objects in it, so you're answer probably works, but the return had to be changed from `[{"_id": "50585c86ded998e77a000002"}]` to `{"_id": "50585c86ded998e77a000002"}`